# What Windows Process / Component mounts the homeDirectory to the homeDrive?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm trying to understand a bit more about the Windows / AD Login Process.

In Active Directory one can set a [homeDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-homedrive) and a [homeDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-homedirectory) on the User Object. The same can be set for local users in lusrmgr.msc. Those settings [correspond to the "Connect: [...] To: [...]"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6822.active-directory-attributes-in-the-aduc-gui-tool.aspx#User_Profile_tab) in the Profile Tab for a Users Properties. [Some people say that it is no longer best practice to use those settings.](https://serverfault.com/questions/663867/is-using-the-ad-home-directory-attribute-to-map-the-home-drive-really-no-longer)

On your a Machine with a User with those settings used one can see what they are set to in the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMESHARE` environment Variables. [After a bunch of searching I found out, that those are set by explorer.exe using the function `shell32!RegenerateUserEnvironment`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606483/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-windows-environment-variables-homedrive-homepath)

I can also see, that windows somehow locally caches the information of those settings, because even with no connection to the domain windows is still able to set the environmentvariables correctly.

So with all that information out of the way I have two questions remaining:

1. Where does Windows locally store that information?
2. What component / process / function does mount the `HOMESHARE` as a Network drive?

Comment: 1. each user's settings are stored in registry, thus the first time a user logs on to a system a AD connection is required. 2. no clue :) but might be the logon process reading the settings from the registry, you could check those...

Comment: I thought so too, but I can't find where in the Registry that information would be saved. I tried to search the whole registry with NirSofts RegScanner; I also tried to monitor where mmc.exe was writing with ProcMon, both didn't yield any results for me.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` is the main KeyName, inside you will find `S-1-5-21-<UUID of domain + sequential no>`which has the Key `ProfileImagePath` the Home Folder for the user whose registry entries you are looking for. Keep in mind that users can have roaming profiles and redirected home folders to company servers in case you do not see a local path.

Comment: That is unfortunatly not what I'm looking for. The value of that key is seen in `USERPROFILE`. `HOMESHARE` and `HOMEDRIVE` are different from that.

Comment: what about this link? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606483/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-windows-environment-variables-homedrive-homepath#:~:text=HOMEDRIVE%20%2C%20HOMEPATH%20and%20HOMESHARE%20(as,persists%20until%20the%20profile's%20unload.)

Comment: I have that link in the question. It only says what sets the environment variables, not from where it loads them. It also dosen't say if or if not explorer is responsible for mounting the network drive.

Comment: check this location in registry `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-<UUID>\Volatile Environment` this is available only when the user is logged on, but contains the `HOMEPATH`- so you might be able to find what process is creating it - the UUID part will be a match to the HKLM Profile List key